# Zend Framework: how to use validator in router.xml

Tags: php, xml, validation, zend-framework, routes

I've created the validator *SportNameValidator* and I want to use it to check variables in the url. How can I put a validator to **routes.xml**?

This is the part of file:

```
<rss_top_news_by_sportname>
<type>Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex</type>
<route>export/rss/top/news/([a-z]+).xml</route>
<defaults>
    <controller>export</controller>
    <action>rssTopNewsBySportName</action>
</defaults>
<map>
    <sportname>1</sportname>
</map>
```

Answer (score 3):

Validators are used to validate user input in forms, not routes. But you can use this validaton mechanism in controller to validate url.

```
$validator = new SportNameValidator();
$valid = $validator->isValid($url_or_part_of_url_you_want_to_validate);
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there some same validaton mechanism in routers?